# FORCE HttpRequest disable cache without Chrome devtools opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cache-control

I have Http request function, that works perfectly on iOS, Android, desktop Opera, but in Chrome it works only with devtools opened. Actually, earlier the same problem was in IE, but I fixed it adding parameters to http request. Currently the function is below:

```
function requestf(path, run)
{
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', path+'&cprv='+(new Date().getTime()), true); 
request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
request.setRequestHeader('expires', 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
request.setRequestHeader('pragma', 'no-cache');

request.addEventListener('readystatechange' ,function()
{
if ((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200))
run( request.responseText);

}
);

request.send();
}
}
```

It works in Chrome without devtools is opened when requests are sent not frequently, but in part of code where this function is calling 10 times per a second it works only if devtools is opened. How to fix it?

Literally before pushing the post question button, I wondered, what if to use random number instead of time?

Comment: You could get the time once and then add 1 with every request.

Comment: @Pointy, seems that I tried that(but -1 instead of +1, that is actually stupidly)

Comment: Seems, that the issue I have is not because of http request

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in my case the issue wasn’t in the xhr in general, but what may help you, if you send request with high frequency, as @Pointy mentioned, is getting time value only once, and just increasing it per each request call:

```
var cache_date = new Date().getTime();

function request(path, callback)
{
cache_date++;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', path+'&cprv='+cache_date, true); 
request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
request.setRequestHeader('expires', 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
request.setRequestHeader('pragma', 'no-cache');

request.addEventListener('readystatechange' ,function()
{
if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200))
callback( request.responseText);
}
);

request.send();
}
```